# Using a table for config

Tags: php, mysql

I'm administrating a simple website for a small society. We take turns to keep our locale clean and up until now, that has been handeled by writing our names on a paper calender.

Now we want to be able to do it online and I've come as far as to have made a working, bookable schedule using a MySQL database. To this I would like to add a simple function to give the person responsible for the cleaning schedule some administrative rights, such as beeing able to lock the schedule for further "bookings".

To accomplish this I was thinking of creating an "schedule_admin"-table, in which certain values could be used as flags to indicate if for example the schedule is locked or not.

The pseduo code would be something like this:

```
SELECT appropriate_col_name FROM schedule_admin
if flag == 'locked'
schedule is read/write
else
schedule is read only
```

Or if you want to lock/unlock the table it would be like:

```
Press button LOCK then
UPDATE schedule_admin VALUE('locked')

Press button UNLOCK then
UPDATE schedule_admin VALUE('unlocked')
```

Or is this way of doing it completely bananas?

Edit: I think I was abit unclear. What I really wanted was some kind of config table, from where the PHP script could extract data. (locked = 0 - allow booking, locked = 1 - don't allow booking).

Comment: Also, check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) out..may or may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I want the page to look different, depending on if it's locked or not. If it's unlocked, display checkboxes to book empty days. If locked, hide checkboxes. I was thinking of storing such flags in an ordinary table.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new column, "lock". Then retrieve the "lock" value and if it's 1 (true) then display only options to view it. If it's 0 (false) display options to book new days.

Comment: Are you talking about the "schedule"-table? Is it is now, each row is a booked day, containing id_schedule, date and id_user. I was thinking of using another table to keep track of administrative actions, where locking the schedule is one of them.